Mysql Query to retrieve featured posts published on the WordPress
I'm trying to build a Mysql Query to retrieve featured posts published on the WordPress homepage via PHP.
I can't understand in which column the fact that an article is featured and published on the home page is stored compared to another not published on the home page.
I tried with a query like this:
SELECT wp_posts.post_title as TITOLO, 
    wp_term_relationships.object_id as ID, 
    wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id as ID1, 
    wp_term_taxonomy.term_id as ID2 
FROM `wp_posts`, 
    `wp_term_relationships`, 
    wp_term_taxonomy 
WHERE `post_status`='publish' 
    and `post_type`='post' 
    and wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id 
    and wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id 
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC 
LIMIT 100;

The resulting list is of both featured and non-featured items..
